# Too Much Space in Text Command

Tags: macros, formatting, bold

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\textdef}[1]
{
{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}
}
\begin{document}

An integer is \textdef{even} if it is divisible by $2$.

An integer is {\color{blue}\textbf{odd}} if it is not divisble by $2$.

\end{document}
```

In the code above, both lines are defined in virtually the same way, yet there seems to be extra space added around the word "even" in the first line.  Where is this extra space coming from, and how can I get rid of it?

[image: spacing issues]

Comment: you are adding the space use  `\newcommand{\textdef}[1]{{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}}` an end of line is a space

Comment: Or you can finish your lines in `\newcommand` by `%` symbols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

End-lines count as spaces if not protected by `%`. It's also preferable to use `\textcolor{blue}{text}` instead of `{\color{blue}text}`.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\textdef}[1]
{                                 <--- one space is here
{\color{blue}\textbf{#1}}         <--- one space is here
}
\begin{document}

An integer is \textdef{even} if it is divisible by $2$.

An integer is {\color{blue}\textbf{odd}} if it is not divisble by $2$.

\end{document}
```

Correct code:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\textdef}[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

An integer is \textdef{even} if it is divisible by $2$.

An integer is \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{odd}} if it is not divisble by $2$.

\end{document}
```

[image]